# Powershell - How to filter value from a variable?

Tags: powershell

I manage to get an output from Invoke-Webrequest for a variable, as below. Now I would like to filter out only value 6895, how can I achieve the filter using sourceIndex?

sourceIndex      innerText

---

```
    131      8962     
    134      6847     
    137      6895     
    237      3831     
    240      1807     
    243      1141     
    347      7368     
    354      4822     
    357      9037     
    574      383 831  
    583      621 807  
    592      281 141
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcpm6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i confess that i have no idea what you mean by `how can I achieve the filter using sourceIndex?`. [*blush*]

however, the object that contains the target value is easy to find using the `.Where()` collection method. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a data set to work with
  replace all of that with a call to your data set using `Import-CSV` or grabbing it from your `I-WR` call.
- sets the target text
- filters the collection using the `.Where()` collection method
- assigns the above to the `$Result` variable
- displays that on screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, repalce this entire block with a call to Import-CSV or the info from elsewhere
$IWR_Result = @'
sourceIndex, innerText
131, 8962
134, 6847
137, 6895
237, 3831
240, 1807
243, 1141
347, 7368
354, 4822
357, 9037
574, 383 831
583, 621 807
592, 281 141
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
#endregion >>> fake reading in a CSV file

$TargetInnerText = '6895'

$Result = $IWR_Result.Where({$_.InnerText -eq $TargetInnerText})

$Result
```

output ...

```
sourceIndex innerText
----------- ---------
137         6895
```